# Directly send money from my Stripe account to my customers bank accounts

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I'm looking for functionality to make direct payments to my Stripe Customers bank accounts without Stripe Connect.

Is it actually possible to do?
Do I have to use any other payment providers for that?

I spent a lot of hours to find correct way of doing such kind of payment flow, but all of them requires Stripe Connect for customer which is unacceptable in my situation.

Comment: You have to use Connect. There are requirements to verify identity of people you send money to for things like anti-money-laundering laws. That means creating a Stripe account for the recipient and having them verify their identity on that account, which is what Connect is for. https://support.stripe.com/questions/know-your-customer-obligations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of this issue was decided to use Wise (TransferWise). Because Stripe does not provide required functionality.